# Multiselect control with large list of options opens a dialog view

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-dialog, multi-select

My mobile website has some multiselect controls. The multiselect that have a little number of items (5) appears normally, like a multiselect (in mobile style/format), but those that have more items than 5 appears like an dialod view, in a new page.
What should I do to prevent the appeareance of view from multiselect?
Thanks!
multiselect code:

```
<div class="field ">
        <label for="offices" class="select">
            Office(s):
        </label>
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Offices, Model.ListOfOffices, new { Multiple = "multiple", data_theme = "a", data_overlay_theme = "c", inline = "true", data_native_menu = "false" })
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only option I'm aware of is the Native form elements option

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html

> Although the framework automatically enhances form elements and
>   buttons into touch input optimized controls to streamline development,
>   it's easy to tell jQuery Mobile to leave these elements alone so the
>   standard, native control can be used instead.
>
> Adding the data-role="none" attribute to any form or button element
>   tells the framework to not apply any enhanced styles or scripting. The
>   examples below all have this attribute in place to demonstrate the
>   effect. You may need to write custom styles to lay out your form
>   controls because we try to leave all the default styling intact.
>
> As of Version 1.1 adding the data-enhance="false" attribute to any
>   container will tell the framework not to enhance any element inside.
>   To activate this functionality, $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled must be
>   set to true. View Configuring Defaults before using it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to used data-role="none" but the multiselect controls doesn't look ok for a mobile website.

Comment: understandable, the device would control the options look and feel at that point. I think jQM uses the dialog to display large sets of options for performance/display reasons.

Comment: A reason I don't want that behaviour is that it is not working so well this view. It becomes tough to close it using the "X" on the left of the dialog. For some reason, it is becoming unresponsive, and if a make back on the page it dissapeare but It change the URL and I can't submit the data from page.

Comment: What about using a listview to display the options?